# Assigning Raster Cell data to Point data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, point

I have 23 sets of raster data for different types of habitat (which I have performed Block Statistics on in Arc10.2, in order to create a 1km grid). I also have 5 different Sets of point data showing presence data for a specific amphibian species. What I need to do is Assign the raster cell data to the point data which overlap. My final aim is to produce a table which will show the percentage of each habitat for each amphibian sighting

For example using great crested newt as one of my 5 species (I will end up with 5 tables) my Table headings could look like this,

GCN Sighting | % woodland | % grassland | % open water | ...% other 20 variables

From this I will produce box plots to illustrate habitat variability for each amphibian species, and hopefully will be able to draw some conclusions from it.

I am quite new to ArcGIS so please phrase it as if you were explaining this to a 5 year old!

Comment: Have you looked at [Extract Values to Points](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000002t000000.htm) or [Zonal Statistics as Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000w8000000) geoprocessing tools?

Comment: Hi Barbarossa, I have tried to use the extract values to points however it would come up with an error stating there was a lock in place? And the Zonal Statistics (The inputs I used we're the point data at 1km and the 1km Raster) but I didn't recieve any sort of percentage. However I will have a look at both techniques in detail and retry them!

Comment: Zonal stats won't do it, as that doesn't involve points. Extract Values or MultiValues to Points, possibly Sample. And for your future steps you're going to want to look at the Summary Statistics tool, case fields in particular.

Comment: @Chris Actually, zonal stats will do just fine provided all points are separated enough to be assigned to distinct cells.  A quick conversion of each species table to a grid will create a single zone and then you're off and running.  But this is not a great method to use, given there are accurate built-in ones referenced by Barbarossa, as well as others such as `combine` (or even just masking the habitat data to this zone and viewing the resulting VAT) that are simpler and faster.

Comment: @whuber That's true, I was more just considering the existing formats/data rather than converting them to something else since it seemed like it would be extra steps/more work. Even if converting, if I'm following the question right, I'd probably look at Zonal Histogram before Stats. Luke - the lock issue may be due to where you're trying to write the output points. Also, it might speed things up to combine your data a bit to run all the analysis in a single go. Do the 23 types of habitat overlap at all? If not you could combine those to one raster. You might also combine your points.